# C++ Garbage collection, templates and operator overriding - can't understand why it throws an error

Tags: c++, templates, garbage-collection, operator-overloading

I am trying to compile a file which defines a garbage collection template and several supporting classes with use of operator overloading. I've tried to run this through MSVC++ 2008, and the compile stops at this particular class:

```
// (The collector defines gc_object_generic_base which
// inherits from gc_object_generic_base and optionally adds
// collector-specific properties.)

template<class garbage_collector>
class gc_object_base : public garbage_collector::gc_object_collector_base {
public:
    gc_object_base() {
        garbage_collector::constructing_gc_object_base(this);
    }

    static void* operator new(size_t sz,
        block_construction_locker_base* lock = block_construction_locker<garbage_collector>().get_this())
    {
        return garbage_collector::allocate(sz, lock);
    }
    static void operator delete(void* p, block_construction_locker_base* lock) {
        return garbage_collector::deallocate(p);
    }
    static void operator delete(void* p) {
        return garbage_collector::deallocate(p);
    }

private:
    // TODO: are arrays worth implementing?
    static void* operator new[](size_t sz) {
        assert(0);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Truncated output for brevity's sake:

```
2>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Compiling...
2>FlashTest.cc
2>C:\test\gameswf\base\tu_gc.h(133) : error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
2>        C:\test\gameswf\base\tu_gc.h(151) : see reference to class template instantiation 'tu_gc::gc_object_base' being compiled
2>C:\test\gameswf\base\tu_gc.h(135) : error C2091: function returns function
2>C:\test\gameswf\base\tu_gc.h(135) : error C2802: static member 'operator new' has no formal parameters
2>C:\test\gameswf\base\tu_gc.h(135) : error C2333: 'tu_gc::gc_object_base::operator new' : error in function declaration; skipping function body
```

Any ideas on where I should start looking at?

Comment: why don't you just show tu_gc.h lines 133 and 135 where the errors reported.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to do that. The source can be viewed at http://tu-testbed.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tu-testbed/trunk/tu-testbed/base/tu_gc.h?revision=1533&view=markup

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same pattern of errors in a different project. It seems to happen when someone has done this somewhere:

```
#define new new(someArgs, someMoreArgs, etc)
```

It's targeted at simple 'new' expressions, but it breaks down if anyone tries to declare any more 'operator new' thingies.

Answer (score 1):

In the opening lines

```
template<class garbage_collector>
class gc_object_base : public garbage_collector::gc_object_collector_base {
```

garbage_collector appears twice here, once as the template parameter and another as an outer-class to gc_object_collector_base, but as it is a template parameter does it not require "typename" here thus:

```
template<class garbage_collector>
class gc_object_base : public typename garbage_collector::gc_object_collector_base {
```

Comment: Adding the keyword results in: keyword 'typename' illegal in base class list; ignored c:\test\gameswf\base\tu_gc.h 124

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of `string` in your code, that I can see.  But I would start by ensuring that you first `#include <string>` before your class delcaration, and then make sure you use `std::string` as your declarator, rather than just `string`.